# Unusual behavior while compiling a demo recursion code using -O3 flag

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-errors

When I am normally compiling this code snippet mentioned below using GCC compiler in a x86 machine then I am getting the expected output **120**.

But as soon as I am compiling this exact code snippet with `-O3` flag then the output is coming as **0** which is not desired.

#### The Code Snippet

```
/* CODE SNIPPET FOR GENERAL RECURSION */
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int n);
int main()
{
    int n=15;
    printf("Sum of all the 15 numbers in recursion = %d  \n",add(n));
    return 0;
}

int add(int n)
{
    if(n!=0) 
      {
        printf( "N Value = %d        \n",n);
        return (n+add(n-1));  /* recursive call */
      }
}
```

- Expected Output= **120**

Can anyone please let me know how the GCC compiler is using this -O3 flag to generate an ambiguous result? What sort of Optimization is -O3 doing?

Command To Compile:

```
gcc     testrecursion1.c -o recursion1  # (EXPECTED OUTPUT)
gcc -O3 testrecursion1.c -o recursionO3 # (AMBIGUOUS OUTPUT)
```

Comment: Just add an alias or something so that you compile with warnings enabled, and you should have a "doh!" moment :)

Comment: Just as an FYI, trailing blanks before a newline are pretty pointless.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using?  4.1.2, 5.3.0, 6.1.0, something else?  It might matter.  Your claimed output is a small subset of the total output you should be getting — what gives?

Comment: Add `-Wall` to the compilation command lines.  Fix the problem!  Don't compile without `-Wall` in future.  (I use much more extensive warning options before running code: `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror` or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, GCC uses -O0 (minus ooh zero), which means "don't optimise at all".

As soon as you enable optimisation however, the compiler will optimise heavily, and in this particular case specialise your `add` function to the input being provided. The last call to `add` will be for `n=0`, so that's the version you'll end up with.

To avoid that from happening, don't hardcode `n=15` in the program, but take it as an argument to your program (so that the compiler doesn't know what values of `n` may be passed in, and so can't specialise the code for those values).

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char* *argv){
    int n=atoi(argv[1]);
    ...
```

And then run: `./recursionO3 15`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Thanks for your time in explaining the scenario